# Upgrade .Net Core 1.0 to 2.0 Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core

I'm trying to upgrade the .net core version from 1.0 to 2.0 but I'm getting some errors. I'm not good at Linux, so I don't understand well what's happening.

I run:

```
apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
```

And I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-sdk-2.1.4 : Depends: dotnet-runtime-2.0.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, I try to install `dotnet-runtime-2.0.5` and I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-runtime-2.0.5 : Depends: libicu55 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After this, I try to install `libicu55` but I already have installed `libicu57`. I don't know what to do.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libicu55 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libicu55' has no installation candidate
betocastillo86@ubuntu-huellitas-prod:~$
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 it was … there’s a catch though,
>   you can choose between LTS (Long Term Support) or not. I chose not to
>   since It’s a VM and I don’t mind newer updates, etc… Turns out that
>   was a bad idea with .NET Core installs! It would seem that once the
>   non LTS is installed you end up with 16.10 which has installed some
>   newer versions of required libraries, namely something called libicu
>   which is now on 57 instead of a required 55.

Source: https://shazwazza.com/post/installing-net-core-101-on-ubuntu-1610/

Try installing the libicu55 manually on your machine (it should run side by side with the newer version on your machine):

1. Download the file from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/amd64/libicu55/download
2. Install it using: `sudo dpkg –i libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb`